# What is the syntax for "if the image style does not exist and if no image style is selected"?

Tags: paragraphs, 10

I'm encountering an issue when calling a preprocess function to load a styled image URL. This issue is based on the question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/318290/how-do-i-get-the-image-url-with-the-same-style-setting-in-manage-display).

The following Preprocess Paragraph function sets the style based on the Manage Display. An error occurs if the Manage Display setting is "None (original image)".

How do we prevent errors during the preprocessing of the function when attempting to load an **image style that doesn't exist** or **when Manage Display is set to None (original image)**?

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

function Mymodulename_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  $paragraph = $vars['paragraph'];
  if($paragraph->field_img[0]){
    // Get image style name
    $component = EntityViewDisplay::load('paragraph.sing.default')->getComponent('field_img');
    $img_style = $component['settings']['image_style'];
    $img = $paragraph->field_img[0]->entity->getFileUri();
    $style_img_url = ImageStyle::load($img_style)->buildUrl($img);
    $vars['style_img_url'] = $style_img_url;
  }
}
```

Render

```
<img src="{{ style_img_url }}">
```

Comment: I wrote an answer and deleted it, because I did not at first understand the question. You have the file's URI. Can you not return that if there is no image style?

Comment: Your question is on my question title. Knowing that syntax could potentially be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended to use the original file URL if no image style is selected.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

function Mymodulename_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  $paragraph = $vars['paragraph'];
  if($paragraph->field_img[0]){
    // Get image style name
    $component = EntityViewDisplay::load('paragraph.sing.default')->getComponent('field_img');
    $img_style = $component['settings']['image_style'];
    if (!empty($img_style)) {
      $img = $paragraph->field_img[0]->entity->getFileUri();
      $style_img_url = ImageStyle::load($img_style)->buildUrl($img);
      $vars['style_img_url'] = $style_img_url;
    }
    else {
      $vars['style_img_url'] = $paragraph->field_img[0]->entity->getFileUrl();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this.

Comment: The "if empty" syntax works here but outputs the wrong URL. It uses "public:", such as "public://original_file_name.jpg."

Comment: Try `...->entity->createFileUrl();` instead of getFileUrl()

Comment: The `createFileUrl()` does the trick.

Comment: Should I update the code?

Answer (score 0):

Source code to get the original file URL on site of img field if no image style is selected along with added checks as well.

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

function Mymodulename_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  $paragraph = $vars['paragraph'];
  // Added check paragraph type Here sing is machine name of paragraph
  // & field_img exist or not
  if($paragraph->getType() == 'sing' && $paragraph->field_img[0]){
    // Get image style name
    $component = EntityViewDisplay::load('paragraph.sing.default')->getComponent('field_img');
    $img_style = $component['settings']['image_style'];
    if($img_style){
      $img = $paragraph->field_img[0]->entity->getFileUri();
      $style_img_url = ImageStyle::load($img_style)->buildUrl($img);
      $vars['style_img_url'] = $style_img_url;
    }else{
      // Get original img path
      $vars['style_img_url'] = $paragraph->field_img[0]->entity->createFileUrl();
      //$vars['style_img_url'] = file_create_url($img);
    }
  }   
}
```

**Note:** Here use `file_create_url()` to get the original file URL i.e. is accessible by the user

if file_create_url() not work then can use createFileUrl()

Comment: I get the error message `The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.` when using the `file_create_url()`.

Comment: if you want to debug why this file_create_url() not work , you can check recent logs ,